# Powershell - Multiple file ext on rename doesnt work

Tags: powershell

I have a large amount of files in a large amount of folders that I want to set to all have the same file extension. Using this works for single file ext

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.PSPath -NewName $_.Name.replace(".webp",".jpg")}
```

But using this for multiple files ext does nothing

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.PSPath -NewName $_.Name.replace(".jpeg.png.webp",".jpg")}
```

I have tried .* for the file ext to cover all of them and adding spaces between the exts but this does nothing either.

Can someone point out where I am being an idiot?

Comment: Have you tried all methods to rename file extensions? The methods to try can be found here <https://sumtips.com/tips-n-tricks/batch-rename-file-extensions-command-prompt-powershell/#:~:text=Rename%20all%20file%20extensions%20in%20a%20folder%20To,works%20only%20in%20the%20directory%20you%20are%20in.>. Also to support you better, could you provide the error your experiencing?

Comment: I can do this command with just one file ext to another or I can do ''cmd ren * .* *.jpg'' per folder but I cant get it to do all folders.
If I do the powershell way with multiple file ext there is no error, I just get the prompt back instantly and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `|` for OR operations.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "\.jpeg$|\.png$|\.webp$",".jpg" }
```

the `\.` is needed to match a literal `.`, and the `$` is needed to tell the command to only match those three strings when they occur at the end of the filename.

Comment: @Theo I intentionally avoided doing that not to confuse the OP, but I guess the regex should be as verbose as needed

Comment: Works spot on. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid renaming parts of the file name that are **not** the extension, I would advise against using `-replace`, unless you treat it as it should by escaping the characters that have special meaning for regex (the dot) and by anchoring the string to replace.

Better use a dedicated .Net function:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.jpeg','*.png','*.webp' -File -Recurse) | Rename-Item -NewName {[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.Name, ".jpg")}
```

or if you do want to use `-replace`:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.jpeg','*.png','*.webp' -File -Recurse) | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\.(jpeg|png|webp)$', '.jpg' }
```

Also, by specifying the extensions in the `-Filter` parameter of Get-ChildItem, you do not iterate **all** files, eventhough they can have extensions you do not want to rename, plus Get-ChidItem will do its job faster.